# Loading new form within a navigation tab in ms Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created the following navigation structure in a Microsoft access 2010 database:

[image]

You can see that there are two tabs, and the data for the tabs is populated with information linked to the ClientID, which is stored in an un-editable textbox at the top of the form.  When the Communications Forms tab is selected, a list of communications forms that have been completed for the specific ClientID is shown.  And there is a button to create a new form.  My question is how do I write the macro so that clicking on the Create New Form button will cause a blank new form to be loaded in the space that is currently occupied by the List of Forms?

Below is what I have so far.  It sends the user to a new form instead of embedding the new form underneath the Communication Forms tab in the current form.  How can I change the below so that the blank new form is loaded under the Communication Forms tab in the current form, so that all the navigation controls remain visible/usable?

[image]

EDIT:

To address HK1's assumptions below, I am adding the following description of the steps I took to create the form in the screenshot above:

```
1.) I created a blank form in design view.
2.) I added a listbox to list client fullname and id, and a textbox to filter the listbox.
3.) I added the clientid and fullname textboxes to the form, and set them to change based on  
    what the user selects from the listbox  
4.) I dragged a navigation control onto the form next to the listbox  
5.) I dragged a form called "ListOfForms" onto a new tab in the navigation control to create the tab  
6.) I added the CreateNewForm command button to the ListOfForms form while embedded in the main form
```

Here is the result of HK1's suggested code:

[image]

While I appreciate it, it does not do what I need.  You can see that it just adds an additional row to the list in ListOfForms. Instead, I need the code to place a blank MyForm in the place of MainForm where ListOfForms is currently located.  Thus, under the CommunicationsForms tab, all the user would see would be a blank MyForm object, which is a different form than ListOfForms.

When I click on the place where ListOfForms is located in Layout View, I see that it is called NavigationSubForm in the Property Sheet.  Thus, NavigationSubForm would swap in MyForm in place of ListOfForms when the user clicks on the Create New Form command button. But if the user clicks on CommunicationForms tab again, ListOfForms would again be placed in NavigationSubForm.

I tried the following:

```
Private Sub cmdCreateNewForm_Click()
    Forms!MainForm!NavigationSubform = MyForm
End Sub
```

But it generates a Runtime Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Next, I tried:

```
Private Sub cmdCreateNewForm_Click()
    Forms!MainForm.NavigationSubform.SourceObject = MyForm  
End Sub
```

This causes the NavigationSubForm to go blank, so that ListOfForms disappears.  This seems like I am on the correct track, but what do I need to do to get it to put a blank MyForm in the NavigationSubForm instead of just an empty space?

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? Would you consider using VBA instead?

Comment: With vba this should be relatively easy?

Comment: Yes, in fact, it appears if you would just set your form's AllowAdditions to Yes/True you wouldn't even need this. Also, I think you're using the word "form" incorrectly. In most cases when you say form you actually mean record.

Comment: @HK1 Thank you.  Can you show me how it would look?  I am new to access.

Comment: @TheLaurens Thank you.  Can you show me how to do it in VBA?  I am new to VBA, but code samples help me learn quickly because I know how to code in other languages.

Comment: Whether or not a form is blank has everything to do with how you set it's recordsource or it's filter. It's a little difficult to understand what you're trying to do here. It's as though you are using MS Access forms as though they are PDF Forms. There's simply no comparison between an Access Form and the old Fillable Paper Forms. They are two completely different things.

Answer (score 2):

The form you have labeled as "List of Forms" appears to be what's called a continuous form, and I'm guessing it's inside a subform control located on a another form. I'm also guessing that your Create New Form button is probably located on the header section of your continuous form. I'm also making the assumption that your continuous form/subform is bound to an editable recordset/recordsource but there's no way I can tell this by looking at the screenshot.

With these assumptions in place, the code for your Create New Form button would probably be something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdCreateNewForm_Click()
    Me.AllowAdditions = True
    DoCmd.GoToRecord, , acNewRec
End Sub
```

If any of my assumptions above are incorrect than it's likely this code won't work as expected.

Be aware that New Records in continuous forms (and datasheet forms) always appear at the bottom of the list. I'm not aware of any easy way of making them appear anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you.  +1 for trying to help.  I tried your code and it adds another row in ListOfForms.  That is not what I want.  Instead, I want a MyForm to display where ListOfForms is (INSTEAD OF ListOfForms), so that users can use their familiar GUI to create a form.  MyForm is rather long and involved, and cannot be summarized with a row in a datasheet.  Also, I added a description of how I created this whole thing in an edit to my original posting above, if that helps you.  Are you able to show how to answer my clarified question?